# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.slim' has no attribute 'model_analyzer'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Running the [DCGANS-tensorflow tutorial](https://github.com/carpedm20/DCGAN-tensorflow), more precisely lines `python download.py mnist celebA` and `python main.py --dataset celebA --input_height=108 --train --crop`, I get the following error:

```
{'batch_size': 64,
'beta1': 0.5,
'checkpoint_dir': 'checkpoint',
'crop': True,
'dataset': 'celebA',
'epoch': 25,
'input_fname_pattern': '*.jpg',
'input_height': 108,
'input_width': None,
'learning_rate': 0.0002,
'output_height': 64,
'output_width': None,
'sample_dir': 'samples',
'train': True,
'train_size': inf,
'visualize': False}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 97, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "/Users/mj305/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
File "main.py", line 77, in main
show_all_variables()
File "/Users/mj305/DCGAN-tensorflow/utils.py", line 23, in show_all_variables
slim.model_analyzer.analyze_vars(model_vars, print_info=True)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.contrib.slim' has no attribute 'model_analyzer'
```

Any ideas what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised what was the problem with this - just needed an updated version of the Tensorflow (had 0.9.0 versus required 0.12.1), and `pip install tensorflow --upgrade` solved my problem.